# Service onTaskRemoved() how to start service again

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

This question asked so many times but i didn't get any solution  for how to start 
service again in onTaskRemoved()

I tried following ways but it wont work for me.

```
Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(alarmService.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,restartServicePendingIntent);
```

Comment: why flag ONE_SHOT?

Comment: @TimCastelijns i want is to use pending intent one time

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.e("FLAGX : ", ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK + "");

        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                this.getClass());
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());

        intent.setPackage(getPackageName());

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                restartServicePendingIntent);

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
```

Actually i no more idea about how it's work, but this code help you..